# How to call ui-sref inside the node js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, redirect, ui-sref

In my backend is node js i am using.I want to call ui-sref call inside the  node js and redirect the front end(use routes).

### I am focusing to go that function

```html
.state('editCompanyProfile',{
                    url:'/editCompanyProfile',
                    controller:'EditProfileCtrl as vm',
                    templateUrl:'auth/register/editCompanyProfileView.html'

                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend you wouldn't call `ui-sref` as that's an angular directive and isn't available to your backend logic.

Instead just do `res.redirect('http://yourdomain.com/editCompanyProfile')` and you'll accomplish what you're trying to do. If you're not using HTML5 routing, then do `res.redirect('http://yourdomain.com/#/editCompanyProfile')`

Comment: It worked.Can't i use ui-serf tag for the redirect the page ..?

Comment: You can only use the `ui-sref` option inside Angular which is seperate from your backend.